# Initialize GPFlow model with empty X and Y

Tags: gpflow

I'm using GPFlow for multidimensional regression and want to compare various kernels starting with an empty X and Y set. But it seems that the library needs set containing value pairs. I thought about initializing with a point far away from my input space but that point would be included when optimizing my hyper-parameters.
Is there any solution I'm missing or workaround?

Thanks for your help!

This is some standard code to initialize my model:

```
import gpflow
k = gpflow.kernels.RBF(input_dim=1, lengthscales=1, variance=1)
x_sample = np.array([])
y_sample = np.array([])
model = gpflow.models.GPR(x_sample, y_sample, kern=k)
```

which leads to the following error:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

And the following snippet leads to:

```
model = gpflow.models.GPR(kern=k)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'X' and 'Y'
```

It would be great if someone had an idea what I could do to initialize my model with an empty set

Comment: When trying to investigate errors, it's often useful to know not just *what* the error was (here: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`) but also *where* it occurs, i.e. the full stack trace... Not needed anymore in this case, I think, but for future issues :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library *can* deal with an empty `X` and `Y` set - but you have to respect the required shapes. Both `X` and `Y` need to have `ndim=2`. When writing `x_sample = np.array([])`, then `x_sample.shape == (0,)` and `x_sample.ndim == 1`. Instead, set `x_sample = np.empty((0, 2))` (and likewise `y_sample = np.empty((0, 2))`, then `ndim=2` and their shape is `(0, 2)` as required.

(Obviously with no data it does not make sense to optimize your hyperparameters, and there isn't anything you can do with the model, really; if you want to just compare kernels you don't need to construct a model to compute the kernel matrices... but that depends more specifically on what you want to achieve!)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! That will help. 
Regarding the second part in the comment. What I'm doing is comparing kernels, acquisition functions and different sizes of training sets. The model is of course fitted to the training data. Hopefully I end up with a combination of those "meta" parameters and hyperparameters for the kernel on synthetic data representing a real process. After that the model is used with the optimized parameters on a real world example.